# bootstrap switch setState using a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I'm trying to set the state of a bootstrap switch with two external buttons, this is the code:

```
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="switch" id="switch" value="1" data-on-text="ON" data-off-text="OFF" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <a id="set_on">ON</a>
        <a id="set_off">OFF</a>
    </div>

<script src="assets/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="assets/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch();
    $( "#set_on" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', true);
    });
    $( "#set_off" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
    });
</script>
```

Clicking on the buttons ON or OFF the switch no not toggle its state.
Looking on the console of the browser I read this error:
**TypeError: $(...).bootstrapSwitch is not a function**

If I try to set the State of the bootstrap switch outside the function in this way:

```
<script>
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch();
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
</script>
```

the switch toggle correctly to the ON state.

Answer (score 20):

Please replace your code with below :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch();

    $( "#set_on" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
    });
    $( "#set_off" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('state', false);
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, was a my mistake, I found the problem, I have other some js file inclusione at the bottom of the file.
If I put the script at bottom works fine, I'm sorry I wasted your time

Comment: The big takeaway for me was that the op's `"setState"` should be `"state"`.

Answer (score 4):

Try wrapping your code inside `$( document ).ready(function() {});`so that all of your DOM elements loads before jQuery code is executed like this :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch();
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
});
</script>
```

try using it in your full script like this -

```
<script>

 $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch();
    $( "#set_on" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', true);
    });
    $( "#set_off" ).click(function() {
        $("#switch").bootstrapSwitch('setState', false);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: In this way I've the same error: TypeError: $(...).bootstrapSwitch is not a function.
Anyway, I had no problem on the code you post, but on the top one ;)
The one you posted works OK without $( document ).ready(function() {});

Comment: Sorry, was a my mistake, I found the problem, I have other some js file inclusione at the bottom of the file.
If I put the script at bottom works fine, I'm sorry I wasted your time

Comment: As of [Documentation](http://www.acceleraise.org/static/public/t1-r1/plugins/bootstrap-switch/#state) , method name must be `set` instead of `setState`.

Answer (score 2):

Just running into this question for my problem, I found a solution that is not documented.

So just do:

```
 $('#switch').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `bootstrapSwitch()`, something like this

```js
$("[name = 'status']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

```html
<input name = "status" type="checkbox">
```